# Android start main activity from home launcher

Tags: android, android-activity, launch

In my app I have a main activity that is started when the app is launched from the app drawer. In the app there is another activity B that can be launched from the main activity.

If I press home while in activity B to return to home, Activity B will be started instead of the main activity if I launch my app through the app drawer again.

Is there a way to make only the main activity start even if the user pressed home in activity B without using noHistory?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html for further informations.

Answer (score 0):

You just don't want to keep state in B, on the Activity B onStop method, just call finish();

Answer (score 0):

I set a separate android:taskAffinity for activity B